# Can I visit Australia after leaving the country without paying a drunk driving fine?

Tags: legal, australia, uk-citizens

My British friend left Australia when he was on a Working Holiday Visa without paying his drink driving fine of $700 and is wondering if he would be allowed back in the country if he pays it, even though it was 2 years ago?

Comment: @GayotFow As I understand it, OP's *friend* is British and the *visa* is Australian, not the other way around (Australia certainly does offer [Working Holiday visas](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/417-)).

Answer (score 6):

Australia requires everyone entering the country who isn't a citizen to be of [good character](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Char) (or have the requirement waived, which is so rare it's not discussed on the website and you'll probably need a lawyer if you're in this situation). This has [specific requirements in Australian law](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/ma1958118/s501.html). Most of these are for particular offenses or sentences, but there is a catch-all:

> (c)  having regard to either or both of the following:
>
> ```
>  (i)  the person's past and present criminal conduct;
>
>  (ii)  the person's past and present general conduct;
> ```
>
> the person is not of good character; or

It's conceivable that an immigration officer might decide that someone who has not paid their fine is not of good character under this subsection.

Other than that, a fine and driving disqualification does not really meet any of the listed requirements which would cause a finding of not passing the character test.

Remember that you need to tick Yes on the landing card and disclose the conviction to the immigration officer. You'll have a chat with the immigration officer, likely about why it took so long to pay the fine, and the officer will assess your character. Ticking No is a great way to guarantee a refusal of entry.

Comment: I'm not suggesting avoiding answering yes to this, but a fine isn't a conviction, right?